# Should an edit that adds a "no wiki summary" tag be rejected?

Tags: discussion, tags, review-queues, edits

A tag that has no wiki summary is (to some extent) ambiguous. I may think I know what the tag means, but others might have a different interpretation.

When reviewing edits I'm inclined to reject an edit that adds such a tag, because a future tag-edit might add a different interpretation to the tag. But I can see how others might think rejecting such an edit would be pedantic - especially if the implied tag interpretation is likely to be the correct one.

So far I've been a coward and skipped the edit to avoid having to make a decision.

Comment: Does the tag help describe the content of the quest? Was there anything else that could have been fixed?

Comment: @TinyGiant Sorry, I was unclear.  By "no wiki summary" tag I meant a tag that has no excerpt, no description, no usage guidance, etc.  Pretty much no tag content other than the tag's name.

Comment: Yes, but does the tag name help describe the content of the question? Sometimes, tags are created and then they get filled in later. If the tag would be appropriate if it had a tag wiki, the proper thing to do would be to edit the tag wiki with the appropriate information.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be rejected. Provided it's use seems consistent with the other questions in the tag and the tags name. You are certainly welcome to add the missing tag-wiki and tag-excerpt when you are reasonably certain of the tags meaning. And kudos for checking each tags appropriateness!

Comment: @TinyGiant I guess my concern is that I accept the edit because I think the tag is appropriate and then someone else edits the tag in such a way as to render the tag inappropriate because they had a different **but equally valid** interpretation of the tag's meaning.

Comment: Until there's a wiki, you can only go after your own best understanding of how it is used *at the moment*. If someone later adds a tag-wiki, that *does not*, actually, neccessarily override current usage. Anyone can challenge it, best on meta, on any grounds, like being the wrong prescription/description, or just a bad tag.

Comment: @Deduplicator but if it's a tag wiki for the [tool] tag, I would certainly reject it.

Comment: Unless I've missed something, you can't create a tag and wiki simultaneously. Creating the tag comes first, then you can add a wiki.

Comment: @Mat I suspect that's part of the problem.  People create a tag and then forget to create the corresponding tag wiki (or don't know that a wiki needs to be created).

Comment: @Mat If you are a relatively low-rep user, can you even create a tag and its wiki and have the wiki show up immediately? (I forgot how wiki edit approval works in this case.)

Comment: @duplode In 1500-1999, you have to create the tag first by adding it to a question and later, once it's accepted, you have to make a second separate edit suggestion for the tag wiki.

Comment: @tepples The implication, then, is that adopting what the question suggests would put 1500-1999 users in a Catch-22.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, because it would make the [create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege meaningless. A policy of rejecting all edits that add a tag with no tag wiki would imply a policy of rejecting all edits that legitimately add a new tag to the site. This would raise the required reputation for creating a new tag from 1500 to 2000 on Stack Overflow and from 300 to 2000 on most other sites.

Counter-suggestion: Once the edit is accepted, indicate after each tag on each question whether or not the tag lacks a tag wiki, to remind users to create a tag as best they can when they see the indication. (Fleshing out this feature request into a new question has been left as an exercise.)

Answer (score 5):

No, you should not have a fixed habit of rejecting these on sight. There's an awful lot of decent tags with no summary. There's also a pretty fair number of acceptable tags with the most execrable summaries imaginable, just a straight Wikipedia copy-paste of "what is an IDE". Neither is a good reason to automatically consider the tag beyond the pale; they're signals that the tag is not as healthy as it could be, but a rare tag can go quite a while without someone stepping up and making a good wiki for it.

Conversely, there are also bad tags with decent summaries despite being new, like [man-in-the-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/man-in-the-browser), which is pretty much just a synonym of [man-in-the-middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/man-in-the-middle). (Maybe on Security.SE it would be worth separating. Here, it isn't.) Approving edits that include that would be harmful, in my opinion.

Tags are a bad place to use blind, rigid rules like this. Use careful judgement when reviewing suggested edits instead. And if you find you're unable to properly evaluate whether a particular tag belongs, just hit <kbd>Skip</kbd> so someone else has a chance.